# Given an integral, give the given equality?

Tags: calculus, integration

I've been given this problem

[image]

These are my attemtps - I'm pretty sure my a and b are wrong. What is the question asking me to do, specifically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Hint**. If you have an equation of the form:
>   $$\int_a^b \! f(g(x)) \, g'(x)\,\mathrm{d}x \,,$$
>   you can change variables: $u=g(x) \, \implies \mathrm{d}u=g'(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$, thus:
>   $$\int_{g(a)}^{g(b)} \! f(u) \, \mathrm{d}u \,.$$
>   And, if $\ F(u): F'(u)=f(u)$, then:
>   $$\int_a^b \! f(g(x)) \, g'(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_{g(a)}^{g(b)} \! f(u) \, \mathrm{d}u = [F(u)]_{g(a)}^{g(b)}=[F(g(x))]_a^b$$

***In your case:***
$$I=\int_{1}^{3}x^2\,(2+2x^3)^3=\frac{1}{6}\int_{1}^{3}6x^2\,(2+2x^3)^3$$
And, like you said $u=2+2x^3 \implies \mathrm{d}u=6x^2\,\mathrm{d}x$. Then, you can change the limits of the integral using the definition of $u$.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance - how does one find f(u)?

Comment: $f(u)$ is just $f(g(x))$, remember that $u=g(x)$. In your particular case, $f(g(x))=(2+2x^3)^3 \implies f(u)=u^3$ using that $u=2+2x^3$ like you did before. In a general case, find $u$ is by guessing or try and error. Am I making myself clear?

Comment: Most defintely... for some reason I was trying to sub u INTO f... and ended up with u^3... now I realize I was being quite a fool. :)

Comment: XD. Ok, I hope you can get the correct answer. I can re-edit my first answer with more "hints" if you can't figure out.

Comment: Oh no, I have long figured it out now... I had gotten everything \MINUS\ that part, I feel like quite the dolt. :) Thanks a lot.

Comment: U R welcome! (=

Answer (score 1):

You want to change your bounds of integration according to your substitution rule: 
$u=2+2x^3$. Think of 1 and 3 as x-bounds. Plug them into your equation to get u-bounds. The question is asking you to re-write your integral in terms of $x$ as an integral in terms of $u$ using the substitution rule that you gave.

Comment: Sure, but I still don't know the exact *INITIAL* equation is asking me.

Comment: By initial equation, do you mean finding the equation for $u$?

Comment: Actually, your edit helped a lot. Thanks. :)